# Error in looping function to detect outliers in each columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, loops, dataframe

I made a function that detects outliers of each columns in dataset, calling it over and over again is not necessary so i made a loop that iterates the function for each columns in dataset. It returns error `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'numpy.str_' and 'numpy.str_'` , i do not know why this happens, it only errors when i use the loop but when calling it on its own with the column as the parameter like `detectoutliers(avo_sales.AveragePrice)` the error does not happen. How to fix this?

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
import scipy.stats as ss

avo_sales = pd.read_csv('avocados.csv')

avo_sales.rename(columns = {'4046':'small PLU sold',
                            '4225':'large PLU sold',
                            '4770':'xlarge PLU sold'},
                 inplace= True)

avo_sales.columns = avo_sales.columns.str.replace(' ','')

print('Data has some outliers, we''ll''be handling outliers then impute missing values with median')

def detectoutliers(column):
    numbers = sorted(column)
    q1, q3 = np.percentile(column, [25,75] , interpolation='nearest')
    print('Q1,Q3 : ',q1,q3)
    iqr = q3 - q1
    lowerBound = q1 - (1.5 * iqr)
    upperBound = q3 + (1.5 * iqr)
    print('lowerBound,upperBound : ',lowerBound,upperBound)
    print('Detection Success')
    return lowerBound,upperBound

for column in avo_sales.columns[2:11]:
    detectoutliers(column)
```

Comment: One of you columns is obviously not of the right type so either cast it to float or don't perform outlier detection on it, maybe provide a sample of your `avo_sales` dataframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this is because your code

```
for column in avo_sales.columns[2:11]:
    detectoutliers(column)
```

operates on column names of your dataframe. You might change it to:

`for column in avo_sales.columns[2:11]:
        detectoutliers(avo_sales[column])`